# scipy.optimize has confusing behavior

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm using `scipy.optimize` to solve a minimization problem. But what it's doing doesn't make any sense. If I don't set a maximum number of iterations, it runs forever (well, 12 hours at least). So I set the maximum number of iterations to something small to test, say 20.

The initial value of my function is 880.770191886. When I run with all the diagnostic outputs (`full_output=True`, `retall=True`) for `scipy.optimize.fmin`, I get:

```
>>dataOut = so.fmin(optimize_grid, coordsOuter, args=(0.5,(65,86,2)), maxiter=20, disp=True, full_output=True, retall=True)                                                         
>>print dataOut[1:]
```

gives:

```
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded
(197.24011337756517, 20, 11207, 2, [array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.55702654, ...,  2.45997569,
    2.47487373,  2.47487373])])
```

So all of that is saying that the minimum of my function takes the value 197.24 etc. And yet, the vector it tried to use at every iteration is the same as the initial vector! So it's not actually doing anything, even though it identified a minimum. I just get the initial vector back out as the answer at every step which is clearly not correct.

Any ideas what the problem is? I can't see any justification for the way it's working since it clearly identified at some point a value for the function that is less than the initial value.

Comment: And what does the final vector look like? Also, can you confirm that these 20 vectors are all equal? I mean, we don't see all the coordinates here.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Yes, if I subtract the final from the initial, I get 0's in every position. Same if I subtract each of the arrays at the iterations from the original.

Comment: So final is the same? And `optimize_grid(dataOut[0], 0.5, (65, 86, 2))` is still 880 instead of 197?

Comment: @LevLevitsky Correct. This is why I'm so confused.

Comment: Maybe it's your function that's the root of the problem? Maybe its result depends on some sort of state that is changed in the process? It'd be great if you could post a self-contained reproducible example.

Comment: Are you modifying the vector given as the input parameter in your objective function, or always returning the same ndarray data buffer? That could explain why the return values seem strange.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem that your are solving is not really ill-posed and scipy.fmin can converge to very good result with few iteration but because of the fact that you only define the `maxiter` parameters it tries to fulfill your request. Have you tries using `xtol` or `ftol` parameters. You haven't mentioned what version of SciPy you are using but they are available from 0.11.

From 0.11 you could also use `scipy.minimize` which gives you more control on the methods and its parameters.